# c# xaml creating a button when another button is clicked

Tags: c#, xaml

I haven't worked with xaml before and then I wondered.
I need to do adding new buttons to stacklayout when another button is clicked.
I know there should be an event handler when the button is clicked:

```
void OnAddNewButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     . . .

}
```

but I don't know what to write in it at all. At the same time, I need the buttons to be created exactly in a certain stacklayout on the application page. Please tell me, I will be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should name the stackLayout. Then, you can create buttons and add them to that stacklayout from code behind.

Here is a basic implementation as a wpf application.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button
        Grid.Column="0"
        Width="150"
        Height="30"
        Content="Add New Button"
        Click="Button_Click"/>

    <StackPanel
        x:Name="ButtonsPanel"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Background="Aqua" />
</Grid>
```

In code behind, you can create a new button and add to the "ButtonsPanel".

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();

        btn.Content="New Button";

        ButtonsPanel.Children.Add(btn);
    }
```